# The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Cors 5.0.0-beta1 in project does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have started learning ASP.Net Core 2.0 recently. I created the project but when I run the Startup.cs I get the following error.

> The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.Cors 5.0.0-beta1 in project
>   *projectName*  does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.

And this is the project.json file

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "userSecretsId": "aspnet5-WebApplication2-2cf34be9-ba73-4035-85b3-2a2e109c4fea",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",

    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta5",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5"
    },

    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
        "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting": "1.0.0-beta5"
            }
        },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    },

    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ],
    "publishExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.xproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Visual studio are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015

Comment: I always wonder why people follow 3 to 4 year old tutorials. Beta 5 is like 4 years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net Core 2.0 does not have `project.json` anymore. I'm guessing you are using old version of visual studio or you don't have latest dotnet core installed on your system.

You must have Visual Studio 2017 15.5

Also you must get latest dotnet core from https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/windows

Comment: I downloaded the latest .net cored sdk.

Comment: You can't use Visual Studio 2015 for asp.net core 2. You need to install visual studio 2017. It's better if you get the latest version